# How to switch to Frame in appium native web view app

Tags: python, iframe, robotframework, python-appium

I have a native android app. In which there is a web view and then it contain a payment iframe. I am unable to switch to iframe. I have tried the following but all of them are giving the same error:

```
switch to frame    PAYMENT_CARD_IFrame --> not working
switch to frame    xpath=//iframe[1] --> not working
switch to frame    xpath=//iframe[@id="PAYMENT_CARD_IFrame"] --> not working
switch to frame    id=PAYMENT_CARD_IFrame--> not working
```

All of them are generating same error which is:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.104)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the driver contexts first and then switch.

```
print(driver.contexts)
webview = driver.contexts[1]
driver.switch_to.context(webview)
```

And make sure webview debug is enabled